# Despite #!/usr/bin/env php I need to call the file with php, why?

Tags: linux, php, shell

I'm trying to call the shell wrapper for phing

```
phing
```

...but it doesn't recognize the env, I get a

```
-bash: phing: command not found
```

...even though the file starts with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
```

Calling the file with

```
php phing
```

works just fine.

The file is executable and I'm calling it from its own directory.

How's that possible?

Comment: What does `which env` show?

Comment: `which env` shows `/bin/env`. No idea what that means, though.

Comment: Is it important to mention that I'm on a vagranted VB?

Comment: So far so good... can you enter a simple PHP script when you run `/usr/bin/env php` and have it do what you expect? (i.e. `<?php echo "foo"; ?>`)

Comment: I'd love to :) how do I make it execute it resp. exit the php context again?

Comment: Run `/usr/bin/env php`. It should give you just a new blank line, no prompt. Enter the PHP script with whatever line breaks you want. Hit Control-D. Watch what happens (if anything).

Comment: Ok, I was missing the Control-D part. Seems to work fine. `<?= "foo" ?>` echoes `foo` after Control-d.

Comment: Then the `/usr/bin/env php` bit works, and I am officially stumped as to why `./phing` (or equivalent) does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. It's not executable.
   `chmod +x phing`
2. It's not in your `$PATH`. Calling a binary without an absolute or relative path tells your shell to look for it in your `$PATH` and to run the first one it finds. Run `which phing` to check if your shell can find it.
3. Run the binary with absolute or relative path.
   `./phing` (in the same directory as `phing`)
   `/path/to/phing`

Comment: Do you have a 3. ? Beause it's neither of those.

Comment: @markus It is almost certainly one (or both) of those. Per your comments on the question you've determined that `/usr/bin/env php` works - that leaves these as the only possibilities. If you think it's not, provide your reasons.

Comment: Instead of `#!/usr/bin/env php`, could you try giving the path to PHP? `#!/usr/bin/local/php` or whatever?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8738005/1207760) actually suggests it to be better practice, anyway. *shrug*

Comment: Appreciate your help. I think I'm getting there. I ruled number 2. out for a lack of understanding how path seems to work. When I'm in the directory where the file lives and call it with `phing` it doesn't work, if I call it with `./phing` it works. I did not know there was a difference.

Comment: For the record. Problem solved with `echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/bin' >> ~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: Right on. `./phing` says run this phing HERE in THIS directory and just running `phing` asks your shell to go run the first `phing` it finds (phinds?) in your `$PATH`. The current directory is not in `$PATH` so it fails. Also, usually you put "custom" paths in front of the default `$PATH`. This will make sense when you go to install a customized Python or something that you want to use, but don't want to replace the *system* Python. In your case, `PATH=/home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH`

Comment: Thanks Aaron, maybe ammend your answer to be more noob-friendly?

Comment: This really isn't a noob targeted site, sorry. I don't mind helping any one of any experience level (as you see) but I don't expect to dumb-down anything on Server Fault for full credit. I will take my -1 as it is.

Comment: I'm not asking you to dumb anything down, I'm asking you to make the answer richer. Explaining your statements and what they mean makes your answer more valuable. Why would you refrain from adding a few explanations when it makes your answer so much more informative for a large number of people who might potentially be interested in it.

Comment: Maybe you're not aware of the fact that there are intelligent software developers out there who are by circumstances forced to do things they're not familiar with (sysadmin) but since they have a general affinity to tech, they get stuff, if you explain it to them (in more than 4 lines). SE sites are wikis!